# Installing 12.04 on a system already running Ubuntu/Windows 7 dual boot help

Tags: 12.04

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04 (10GB) and Windows 7 (450GB) in a dual boot configuration. I also have about 10GB of a partition for ASUS recovery, but I doubt I need it. I love Ubuntu so much that I want to make it the only OS on my hard drive. My question is, can I just use the liveCD to install Ubuntu and select the option in the installer to "erase disk and install Ubuntu" and have the installer delete my current dual boot of ubuntu/windows7 and everything off my hard drive? Also, if Im installing Ubuntu as the only OS, do I need to defrag my hard drive at all before I do this? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is your windows installed in 450 GB partition entirely.

Comment: my windows is installed in the 450 entirely w two other separate partitions for ubuntu and a recovery partition for asus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ""erase disk and install Ubuntu""

If you have another Storage , do a backup of required data , if by "erase disk" you mean ERASING everything in hard drive ,YES it is possible through Live CD.

Or if you have other unspecified partitions then for deleting the Dual Boot configuration ,  during installation you will get the option to delete create or format Partitions already available. Where you can clear the Dual Boot by deleting the Windows Installation drive and Ubuntu Installation Drive ( Your Data will also be deleted , so Backup is a wise thing to do if required).

Now you are ready to install Ubuntu as per your Convenience.

As far as Defragging is Concerned , no you don't need to defrag the Partition  ( If you formatted in ext4 format) as long as you don't want to make it usable by windows. If Formatted in NTFS , then it may need defragging by Windows . Defragging has different meaning in Linux/ Ubuntu , it defrags inodes to boost performance.

Answer (score 1):

No defragging needed.

- If you want take a backup of your Ubuntu system just now ( Optional )
- Then bang in your live CD and format the disk then install Ubuntu
- Then you can restore your current install ( Optional if followed step 1 )

"Erase disk and install Ubuntu" - This will do as exactly as you need

But your plan seems sound. Just use the Live CD as stated and you will be all good. Leaving you with one large Ubuntu Install :)

Bill

Answer (score 1):

You can just install a fresh copy of ubuntu without defraging the hard disk, but remember this will erase everything on your hard disk so i recommend making a back-up of important document. Ubuntu installation menu is much clear and easy, go for option number one on the installation menu and yes its possible to use a live CD.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the ASUS recovery partition. 
If the disk was partitioned correctly Recovery would be the first (primary) 
partition. (You could change your mind later and 10GB is not much "waste".)

The rest could be devoted to Ubuntu. 
Again it is best to make at least 2 new partitions - one for / root 100GB is enough,
and another for data. (+1 for swap).

All new partitions can be logical as Ubuntu/Linux does not need primary partitions for installation.

You could leave also some space unpartitioned where you could install newer Ubuntu/Linux version later for experiments. Dual booting different Linux versions is handled by GRUB pretty easy.

Comment: If I used the 12.04 installer to erase the entire disk to install Ubuntu, does the installer automatically create a root and swap? I'm not really sure what swaps purpose is